# Finding last day of month

Tags: excel, vba

I've got worksheet of employeers and dates with hours worked. I want to archive employeers from last 3 months to another sheet, so I'm going with this:

```
Sub Archive()
    Worksheets("DATA").Activate
    Dim date1 As String, date2 As String
    Dim date1Cell As Range, date2Cell As Range, valRng As Range, row As Range, names As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Set valRng = Range("A1:A1000")
    date1 = Format(Range("E2"), "yyyy-mm-dd") 'It's 2020-01-01
    date2 = Format(Range("E4"), "yyyy-mm-dd") 'It's 2020-03-01

    Set names = Worksheets("DATA").Cells(6, 1)
    names.EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Rows(.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    End With
    Cells(LastRow, 1).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial

    Worksheets("DATA").Activate
    For Each i In valRng
        If i.Text = date1 Then Set date1Cell = i
        If i.Text = date2 Then Set date2Cell = i
    Next i

    Range(date1Cell, date2Cell).EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Cells(LastRow, 1).Offset(2, 0).PasteSpecial


End Sub
```

So now is my question: how can I find the last day of month in `date2` to have included dates selection until 2020-03-31? Like on screen, I need to select rest of dates below 2020-03-01.

[image: Text]

I've tried this but it's incorrect
`If i.Text = WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(date2, 0) Then Set date2Cell = i`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you always want the last day of the month according to the date in E4, that would be

```
date2 = Format(WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Range("E4"),0), "yyyy-mm-dd")
```